# How to use "import" in python?

Tags: python, syntax, scikit-learn, python-import

If I use `from sklearn import *` or `from skleanr import datasets`, then I can use datasets in the following way: `iris = datasets.load_iris()`.

However, `import sklearn` and `import sklearn as sk` do not work as I expect. For example I cannot use `sklearn.datasets.import_iris()` or `sk.datasets.import_iris()`. Do I misinterpret the import syntax? And it it is the case, what is the correct way to use import.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Nested packages and import and referencing a nested package is often confusing and has nothing to do with the import syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you are not misinterpreting it. It's the package structure of this particular project.

When you import `sklearn`, you import a special python file `__init__.py` in a directory `sklearn`, that has *inside* of it another package called `datasets`. But if `sklearn` itself doesn't import the nested package into it's `__init__.py` file, you cannot use attribute traversal to get to that nested package.

The solution is to import the nested package explicitly, yourself:

```
import sklearn.datasets
```

Comment: In addition, it may be useful to know that the statements `import sklearn as sk`, `import sklearn.datasets` let you use `sk.datasets` later in the code.

Comment: The confusing thing is probably that Numpy does export all its subpackages -- for scikit-learn, this simply isn't feasible because of the size of the package.